# Micronaut: Test POST request

Tags: rest, post, micronaut

In my Micronaut app I have a simple REST controller:

```java
public class Response {
    private String code;

    public Response(String code) {
        this.code = code;
    }
}

@Controller("/api/test")
public class TestController {

    @Post("/")
    public Response index() {
        return new Response("OK");
    }
}
```

How can I tests this edpoint? I tried using

```java
@MicronautTest
public class TestControllerTest {
    @Inject
    EmbeddedServer server;

    @Inject
    @Client("/")
    HttpClient client;

    @Test
    void testResponse() {
        String response = client.toBlocking()
                .retrieve(HttpRequest.POST("/api/test/"));  // FIXME `HttpRequest.POST` requires body
        assertEquals("{\"code\": \"OK\"}", response);
    }
```

but `HttpRequest.POST` requires an additional `body` argument to be specified. In my case there is no body to be sent. (In the real code it is a request to initialize a new object and thus it has to be POST).

Answer (score 4):

Usually, when you implement a POST action, you expect that there is a body sent with the request. In your example, you don't accept any POST body, but you still need to pass anything in the unit test.

You can instantiate the `HttpRequest` object in the following way:

```groovy
HttpRequest.POST("/api/test/", "");
```

You can't pass `null`, it has to be some non-null value (like an empty string.)

Comment: You can pass null.

Comment: I encountered a similar problem, after setting the content type for the request and response on the HttpRequest.POST worked for me. The code snippet is - 
HttpRequest.POST("/api/test/", "")..contentType(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
                .accept(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN));